# Why is this causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I'm trying to make a simple script.  Basically, I want it to find the lowest price of an item on a website called ROBLOX.  For some reason, this script is causing an infinite loop which crashes my Chrome.  Can anyone help

```
function getLowest(id) {
    var give;
    for (var page = 1; page < 33; page++) {
        var link = "http://www.roblox.com/catalog/browse.aspx?CatalogContext=1&Subcategory=9&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=" + page + "&IncludeNotForSale=false&LegendExpanded=true&Category=3";
        $.get(link, function(data) {
            for (var item in data) {
                if (data[item]["AssetId"] == id) {
                    give = data[item]["BestPrice"];
                }
            }
        })
    }
    if (give) {
        return give;
    }
}

console.log(getLowest(prompt("Enter the ID to find the lowest price of")));
```

Comment: How do you know there’s an infinite loop involved, and are you using an otherwise stable Chrome? This looks more like it just returns nothing, since the request hasn’t completed by the time you `return give;`.

Comment: I can tell it loops infinitely because I was writing to the console earlier.

Comment: I second minitech's comment. Also, if you're crashing Chrome, it's probably by trying to open 32 HTTP connections at the same time.

Comment: Note that, because of this, you’re requesting all 32 pages at once, if that somehow causes crashes with your setup.

Comment: @David: Where were you writing to the console?

Comment: @Mini I was writing to the console inside of the $.get

Comment: Did you write inside of the loop? The body of the loop executes once for every character in the HTML of the page you requested, which is a lot, times 32. That would also explain any crashing much better.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, thanks for the help.

This is what I ended up with:

```
function getLowest(id) {
    for (var page = 1; page < 33; page++) {
        var link = "http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?CatalogContext=1&Subcategory=9&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&PageNumber=" + page + "&IncludeNotForSale=false&LegendExpanded=true&Category=3";
        $.get(link, function(data) {
            for (var item in data) {
                if (data[item]["AssetId"] == id) {
                    console.log(data[item]["BestPrice"]);
                    return;
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

getLowest(prompt("Enter the ID to find the lowest price of"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not facing an infinity loop problem, but an asynchronous loading problem.

```
for (var page = 1; page < 33; page++) {
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        for (var item in data) {
            if (data[item]["AssetId"] == id) {
                give = data[item]["BestPrice"];
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Assuming you are using jQuery's `$.get` for querying these pages, the default behaviour for `$.get` is to query the page in asynchronous. Thus this loop will finish without waiting for all the callback in `$.get` being called, which suggests that `give` will remain undefined when exiting the loop.

The solution would be the one you suggest in your answer, or

- force `$.get` to be synchronised by using `$.ajax({ url: link, async: false }).done(function(data) {})`'
- using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to do the async collection, and rewrite the function with a callback after all query work done.